Minimum absolute value of sum of signed square roots
Deleted for downvotes and poor description, will work on it and repost with more details and my partial efforts. Admins please delete.

I guess your question is downvote-prone as some people want you to show more effort.

Not sure about the connection to CLT, but this is an instance of the partition problem, and there is a solution with absolute value approximately 7.1601E-11.
You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $x_j$ be a binary decision variable, and let $s$ and $t$ be nonnegative decision variables.  The problem is to minimize $s+t$ subject to
$$\sum_{j=1}^{100} \sqrt{j}(2x_j-1) - s + t = 0$$
The idea is that $x_j=0$ corresponds to a minus sign, $x_j=1$ corresponds to a plus sign, $s$ corresponds to the positive part of the sum (that is, $s=\max(\sum, 0)$), and $t$ corresponds to the negative part of the sum (that is, $t=\max(-\sum, 0)$).
Related:

Partition square root from 1 to 50 into two sets of equal sum
Choose signs such that $\pm\sqrt{1}\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\dots\pm\sqrt{2022}$ is as close as possible to $0$.

